# На сколько правильно/не правильно использовать Transform: Scale при адаптивной верстке

Tags: css, вёрстка, frontend, адаптивная-верстка

Есть макет допустим 1400 шириной. У него есть кнопки с большим шрифтом  допустим 25, и большими размерами самих кнопок, допустим 50 на 200.

Я использую медиазапрос и при ширине экрана меньше 500 пикселей, просто transform scale эту кнопку в 0.5 раза. Что бы не переписывать все стили для этой кнопки.

Можно ли так делать?

Comment: Для кнопок, возможно и прокатит, хотя я бы не поленился и переписал стили, так как кратное изменение затронет и отступы от края кнопки до текста и размер самих текстов. Возможно текст я бы уменьшал не кратно, а, так сказать, в более медленном темпе. Если же речь будет не о кнопках, а о блоках div, которые могут стоять рядом на большом разрешении, а при малой ширине экрана выстроятся в одну колонку, например, я тем более переписал все стили, а не пользовался сжатием.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но не забывайте, что при расчете позиций элементов браузер не принимает во внимание трансформацию. Т.е., при ширине экрана все элементы (в том числе и сама кнопка) будут считаться и позиционироваться так, словно кнопка все еще 50*200 пикселей - и только потом кнопка ужмется, оставив вокруг себя пустое место.

Лучше перепишите необходимые стили для кнопки, вернее будет. И производительнее.